# compareTo is asking me to cast, and I do not know why

Tags: java

Can someone explain why I am getting this error: **The method compareTo(AVLNode) is undefined for the type AVLNode**

Here is a shortened version of my Tree class:

```
public  class AVLTree< E extends Comparable<E> >
{
    private AVLNode<E> root ;

    public AVLTree()  
    {
        this.root = null;
    }

    public void insert ( AVLNode<E>  item ) 
    {  
        if( item.getLeft().compareTo(item.getItem() ) < 0) //ERROR IS HERE
        {
        }
    }  

}
```

Below is my a short version of my Node class

```
class AVLNode <E extends Comparable<E> >   
{   
private AVLNode<E>  item;
private AVLNode<E>  left;   

public AVLNode ( AVLNode<E> item) 
{  
    this.item = item;
    this.left = null;
}  

public AVLNode( AVLNode<E> item, AVLNode<E> lft ) 
{
    this.item = item;
    this.left = lft;
}

public AVLNode<E> getItem()
{
    return this.item;
}
public AVLNode<E> getLeft()
{
    return this.left;
}
```

}

Comment: Why is `item` an `AVLNode<E>` instead of an `E`? Why aren't you comparing items with items?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `AVLNode` class should obviously look like this:

```
public class AVLNode<E extends Comparable<E>> {
    private E item;

    //...

    public int compareTo(final E obj) {
        return this.item.compareTo(obj);
    }
```

Difference:

- `item` should be of type `E` not `AVLNode<E>` because you want to store an *E* and not a `AVLNode`.

To state, that your `AVLNode`s are comparable, they could implement `Comparable<T>` themself by just delegating to `E#compareTo()` method:

```
public class AVLNode<E extends Comparable<E>> implements Comparable<AVLNode<E>> {
    private E item;

    //...

    @Override
    public int compareTo(final AVLNode<E> other) {
        return this.item.compareTo(other.item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your `Comparable` base class assumes you're comparing to `E`s when you want to compare to `AVLNode<E>`s

So change it to inherit `Comparable<AVLNode<E>>` and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

`getLeft()` returns an `AVLNode`. You try and call `getLeft().compareTo(...)`. This requires that `AVLNode` provides a matching method.

From this:

```
class AVLNode <E extends Comparable<E> >   
{   
    private AVLNode<E>  item;
    ...
```

It looks like your nodes can only hold other nodes. Presumably your items should actually be of the comparable type `E`. Then you can retrieve the item and call `compareTo()` on that.

Answer (score 0):

That's because `AVLNode` doesn't have a method called `compareTo()` if you implement one then the issue should be solved.

You should also decide whether your want to compare `E` vs `E` or `AVLNode` vs `AVLNode`